# ORACLE Trigger Code

Tags: oracle, triggers, concatenation

I want to concatenate two or three fields in in ORACLE datbase trigger, I have to code and is working fine..

Here is a snippet

```
 tes.VAKEY := +:new.KUNNR || +:new.BANKS || +:new.BANKL || +:new.BANKN
```

so, I get the concatenated value of KUNNR, BANKS, BANKL and BANKN in VAKEY which is correct, but the problem is it looses trailing spaces.

for ex.

```
Value of KUNNR - 10 char = '0000001111' 
        Value of BANKS - 3 char = 'IN'
        Value of BANKL - 4 char = '1234'
        Value of BANKN - 6 char = '123456',
```

then I get VAKEY = '0000001111IN1234123456', so the 3 char field BANKS has only a 2 char value
but I want to VAKEY = '0000001111IN 1234123456', the space in the field after 'IN' should be preserved..

Please help me with this.

---

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZIF_CU_KNBK_TRG AFTER
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OR
  DELETE
    ON SAPSR3.KNBK FOR EACH ROW DECLARE tes SAPSR3.ZIFIM%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
    IF inserting THEN
      tes.MANDT := +:new.MANDT;
    elsif updating THEN
      tes.MANDT := +:new.MANDT;
    ELSE
      tes.MANDT := +:old.MANDT;
    END IF;
    tes.OBJTP := 'CU';
    LPAD(old.KUNNR,000010,'');
    LPAD(new.KUNNR,000010,'');
    LPAD(old.BANKS,000003,'');
    LPAD(new.BANKS,000003,'');
    LPAD(old.BANKL,000015,'');
    LPAD(new.BANKL,000015,'');
    LPAD(old.BANKN,000018,'');
    LPAD(new.BANKN,000018,'');
    IF inserting THEN
      tes.VAKEY := +:new.KUNNR || +:new.BANKS || +:new.BANKL || +:new.BANKN;
    elsif updating THEN
      tes.VAKEY := +:new.KUNNR || new.BANKS || +:new.BANKL || +:new.BANKN;
    ELSE
      tes.VAKEY := +:old.KUNNR || +:old.BANKS || +:old.BANKL || +:old.BANKN;
    END IF;
    tes.TIMSP := TO_CHAR(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF');
    tes.TABNM := 'KNBK';
    IF inserting THEN
      tes.UPDKZ := 'I';
    elsif updating THEN
      tes.UPDKZ := 'U';
    ELSE
      tes.UPDKZ := 'D';
    END IF;
    INSERT
    INTO
      SAPSR3.ZIFIM VALUES tes;
  END;
```

can you please check this? if my syntaxx is wrong, I am using ORACLE database on SAP , so I cannot check at server level what is wrong, but erorrs came in after adding this LPAD command only..

---

So this is my final query, which I feel should work too, but for some reason it is not working, I will try to dig deep into it, but it would really help if you can check this once?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ZIF_CU_KNBK_TRG AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SAPSR3.KNBK FOR EACH ROW declare tes SAPSR3.ZIFIM%ROWTYPE; begin if inserting then tes.MANDT := +:new.MANDT; elsif updating then tes.MANDT := +:new.MANDT; else tes.MANDT := +:old.MANDT; end if; tes.OBJTP := 'CU'; if inserting then tes.VAKEY := +RPAD(:new.KUNNR,000010,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKS,000003,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKL,000015,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKN,000018,''); elsif updating then tes.VAKEY := +RPAD(:new.KUNNR,000010,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKS,000003,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKL,000015,'') || +RPAD(:new.BANKN,000018,''); else tes.VAKEY := +RPAD(:old.KUNNR,000010,'') || +RPAD(:old.BANKS,000003,'') || +RPAD(:old.BANKL,000015,'') || +RPAD(:old.BANKN,000018,''); end if; tes.TIMSP := to_char(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP),'YYYYMMDDHH24MISSFF'); tes.TABNM := 'KNBK'; if inserting then tes.UPDKZ := 'I'; elsif updating then tes.UPDKZ := 'U'; else tes.UPDKZ := 'D'; end if; insert into SAPSR3.ZIFIM values tes; end;
```

Comment: your LPAD is incorrect and in the wrong place, you need to do the following

if inserting then tes.VAKEY := +RPAD(:new.KUNNR,10,' ') || +RPAD(:new.BANKS,3,' ') || +RPAD(:new.BANKL,4,' ') || +RPAD(:new.BANKN,6,' ');

Comment: what error are you getting with your latest code?

Comment: one thing i have noticed about your latest code, you have no space between the quotation marks, so '' should be ' '

Answer (score 0):

use `RPAD(BANKS,3,' ')`

this "pads" the end of the field to 3 characters using spaces, but only if the value in the field is shorter than 3 characters

there is also an `LPAD` option which fills from the front of the field